What are the rules of pavitrata(cleanliness) which are to be followed by anyone in Sanatan dharma and where can I find them online?
There are certain rules of sauchachar and pavitata(cleanliness) which are to be followed while cooking or distributing food, snan, japa, puja etc in Sanatan dharma although today mostly no one is aware of them and no one is following them but what are these rules and where can someone find them online?

In Sanatan Dharma, sauchachar (cleanliness) and pavitata (purity) are essential principles observed in various activities like cooking, food distribution, bathing, chanting (japa), and worship (puja). These practices aim to create an environment of physical and spiritual purity, believed to enhance the efficacy of religious and daily activities.
Key Rules of Sauchachar and Pavitata in Sanatan Dharma

Personal Hygiene and Cleanliness:

A person involved in cooking, distributing food, or performing rituals must be in a state of cleanliness, usually achieved by taking a bath (snan) before beginning these activities.
Clothes worn during these activities should be clean, and traditionally, wearing natural fibers like cotton is encouraged to retain purity.

Cleanliness of Surroundings:

The space for cooking, worship, or other religious activities should be clean and free from impurities. In some traditions, the kitchen or puja room is even treated as a sacred space where one does not wear shoes and avoids carrying impure items.
Many households still observe practices like sweeping the kitchen or altar area before use and refraining from certain activities like eating in these spaces.

Pure and Fresh Ingredients:

For cooking and offering food in religious contexts, only fresh, pure, and sattvic (wholesome) ingredients are used. In some traditions, certain foods like garlic and onions are avoided, as they are believed to have tamasic (dulling) qualities that could interfere with spiritual purity.

Conscious Intent and Attitude:

The person preparing food or performing rituals is expected to maintain a peaceful, respectful, and mindful state. Anger, pride, or agitation are believed to diminish the sanctity of the food or ritual.

Proper Disposal of Leftovers:

Leftovers from rituals or food offerings (prasadam) are traditionally handled with respect. In many traditions, prasadam is distributed and consumed immediately, and any excess is given away to prevent waste.

Purity in Food Distribution:

When distributing food, one must avoid direct contact with the food, using clean utensils or wearing gloves. In some communities, this is symbolically performed by using the right hand for serving or wearing a fresh cloth around the hand.

Observing Time for Religious Practices:

Specific times, such as early morning, are often preferred for snan, japa, and puja as these hours are considered more conducive to spiritual activities due to atmospheric purity and calmness.
Finding Resources Online
Most of these rules are detailed in ancient texts and scriptures of Hinduism, such as:
Manusmriti (Manu's Code of Law): Contains elaborate guidelines on personal hygiene, cooking practices, and other purity-related rules.
Yajnavalkya Smriti and Parashara Smriti: These offer similar instructions on conduct related to cleanliness and purity.
Ayurveda Texts like Charaka Samhita and Sushruta Samhita: While focused on health, these also include guidelines on hygiene and diet.
Bhagavad Gita and Vedas: Though not exhaustive on sauchachar, they give principles that relate to purity and cleanliness in life and ritual.
For online resources:

sacred-texts.com and vedabase.io: These websites offer translations of many Hindu scriptures and commentaries.

Advaita Ashrama and Ramakrishna Mission: These institutions provide translations and books that discuss Hindu rituals and practices, including cleanliness and purity guidelines.

Digital libraries like archive.org or jstor.org: They host digitized copies of Hindu texts and research papers related to traditional Hindu practices.


These resources can provide detailed insights into how sauchachar and pavitata are intended to be practiced and adapted in modern life.

For all kinds of information related to cleanliness you should refer the book "kya kare kya na kare"
